# $k$ and $i$ are algebraically dependent for all real k?I think:

Tags: abstract-algebra

$k$ and $i$ are algebraically dependent for all real k?I think:

$P(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2x_2+x_2$,where  $P(i,k) =0$

Comment: Yes, the *set* over $\Bbb Q$, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence).

Comment: In other words, since $i$ is algebraic, we can conclude that $i$ is algebraically dependent with respect to anything $k$.